# Как в ChoiceType добиться, чтоб был множественный выбор с чекбоксами и группировкой?

Tags: symfony, symfony-form

Вот чего нужно добиться (дизайн такой)

[image: Вот чего нужно добиться (дизайн такой)]

При выставлении элементу ChoiceType опций

```
'expanded' => true,
'multiple' => true,
```

пропадает группировка (в choices передается двумерный массив).

Очень жду каких-то светлых идей.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ChoiceType так не настроить.

Сделал через HTML.